# Military records for the Battle of Waterloo?

Tags: germany, army

My great-great grandfather Gottlob Daniel fought with the German army under Gen. Bluecher in the Battle of Waterloo. I have a medal he received which has been passed down thru the family. He was a corporal. Is there a military record for him? Gottlob Fredrich Daniel was born in Germany Feb. 22, 1795 and died July 23, 1874.

Comment: Gottlob or Gottlieb?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Please take the [tour] and look at the [help] to learn more about how the site works.  What source material have you looked at so far?